# How can I fill out a Typeform with Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, typeform

I now how to fill out a Typeform with Selenium but I want to learn more with requests so I want to fill out a from with Python. The problem is when I examine the network I can't find any data being posted. I have a solution to solve the captcha but where can I find the posted data I do input?

https://www.nakedcph.com/en/745/nike-dunk-low-sp-plum-cu1726-500-fcfs-raffle

Answer (score -1):

Python requests can`t help you, because Typeform login page is generating by javascript.

Comment: I get this error ``` form = page.forms[0]
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: @Pytronik what `url` did you use ?

Comment: the url of the typeform

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.